# Firestore API key in an extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a Chrome extension.

The extension creates a unique code that corresponds with an url that the user provides.

I write this url and the uID to my Firestore database.

```
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
var uID = randomID();
db.collection("links").doc(uID).set({
url: url
})
```

But now everyone that has my API key (that is stored in a plain JS file) can write to the database, and I need the extension to be able to write to the database.

Is there a way of securing the database for a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to secure your database. First you should make your plugin require some form of authentication to Firebase/Firestore.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

That would make your plugin users not connect anonymously. Then you can apply rules to your Firestore to protect data where needed.

If you use the chrome identity API you may be able to lift on the Google ID of your users. Here is what seems like a solid example extension showing off the process.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

At our work make use of the custom token functionality Firebase offers so we can use our own identity provider, which works great too, if you need it.

Stick to the docs, they do explain it fairly well.